# w3wp.exe process QueryFile failure on Sysinternal Process Monitor

Tags: iis-7

I am running the Process Monitor tool from sysinternals and I see a lot failures from IIS (w3wp.exe) with Operation QueryFile having a result of "NO SUCH FILE". They are all images in the applications themes directory with web.config appended!

example:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebapp\App_Themes\blueTheme\images\icon.png\web.config

Comment: Are you using ProcessMon to troubleshoot a problem with your web application? If so, what's the problem?

Comment: I was just trying to identify what processes were reading/writting from disk. Noticed a difference in performance between two identical servers in hardware. I do see the issue mentioned above in both of them - so is not the cause of the original problem, but i wanted to eliminate it in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer and the solution:
http://blogs.iis.net/steveschofield/archive/2009/09/19/control-web-config-inheritance-with-iis-7-asp-net-options.aspx